# Can I / Should I upgrade a new ASP.NET MVC 2 RC project to jQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Are there recommendations for/against upgrading the included jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that 1.4.1 is out and Resig has announced this is the [version shipping with VS2010](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1076872), I would go for it.

Comment: +1. I have a personal project which I don't intend to ship for a while; I upgraded that right away, and will upgrade to the point releases as they're available. I also have commercial projects which must ship soon. They are staying at 1.3.2 until after the release.

Comment: @Craig: By those criteria, I should go for the upgrade now... this is a small-scale internal greenfield project that may get bigger if it turns out to be popular.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: You should include that info in your question next time. Your question implies upgrading an existing app to the latest version, which I wouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do it.

I have updated some of my websites without any issues.

Comment: This answer adds nothing, you could at least state your reasons/insights for upgrading.